# Считать данные из окна, для последующей вставки в БД microsoft access

Tags: база-данных, ms-access, окно

Здраствуйте, у меня такая проблема, я задумал заполнить БД microsoft access параметрами из ГОСТов(болтов, винтов, гаек, шайб и т.п.), эти параметры я хочу взять из стандартных изделий КОМПАС-3Д. Что я хочу - необходимо добыть из окна все записи в таблицу(EXCEL, порядка 200 записей) ЛЮБЫМ способом - вручную их вводить не охото.

Может есть у кого-нибудь какие идеи, как это можно организовать
[image: пример окна]